# sql : add euro sign and round the number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application where I can download data to excel file.
The problem is that I need to add euro sigh to some fields.

I had a simialar problem with date.
In excel it was 54656434
It changed in normal date after using `convert(varchar,senddate,105)`

Is there something that looks like that to add euro sign and round it to 2 decimals ???

EDIT:

In excel i get the number like 1,55435 
I need the output be like € 1,55

Comment: What does a typical field contain? Rounded to what precision?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: What about values like 123456,7890123?

Comment: 123.456,79 must be the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of convoluted... let me know what you think. Replace `'1,55435'` with your field.

```
SELECT CONCAT('£', CAST(CAST(1,55435 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS CHAR(55)))
```

I'm in the US, so I'm not sure if decimals can be changed to use commas instead of periods.

Edit: Also, try this: `SELECT CONCAT('£', FORMAT(1,55365, 2))`. Let me know which works.

Comment: I do get an error if i try this in new query 
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: The data type is money ( i dont know if this is important for the solution)

Comment: Yes, the data type is important.  Try after my edit.  Like I said, I'm not sure how commas vs decimal points are for different regions or settings.

Comment: Thnx man this dit the trick it's now an point instead of comma so its 1000.00 instead of 1000,00 but it's oke ;)  The code that worked is SELECT CONCAT('£', CAST(CAST(vat AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS CHAR(55))) i will try your new edit also but it worked thnx

Comment: The second example gave some errors i am keeping the first 1 thnx again for ur help